# Use vuetify in storybook vue need an appropriate loader

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, storybook

I have tried to import vuetify in the configuration file in storybook but gets an error saying:

" Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
@import '../../styles/styles.sass' "

the configurations file looks like this ./.storybook/config.js):

```
import { configure } from '@storybook/vue';
import '../src/plugins/vuetify';

configure(require.context('../stories', true, /\.stories\.js$/), module);
```

I have a story with vuetify components inside. The story looks like this (./stories/3-priceStock.stories.js):

```
import Pricestock from './../src/components/organisms/priceStock.vue';
import priceStockDescription from './descriptions/PriceStock.js';

export default {
  title: 'Organisms',
};

export const priceStockCom = () => ({
  components: { Pricestock, priceStockDescription },
  data() {
    return {
      productItem: "data",
      productItemProce: "data",
    }
  },
  template: '<div><priceStockDescription /><pricestock :priceInformation="productItemProce" 
  :productInformation="productItem">hej</pricestock></div>'
});
```

How do I load vuetify inside storybook?

Comment: How about your webpack.config.js

Comment: You may need sass loader configured for Storybook. Try this example: https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#examples

Comment: @DavidJapan I have no webpack.config.js file in my project.

Comment: @KingGary still getting the same error